# An estimate of the integral of the higher order derivative of a bump function

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\kappa_1>0$, $\beta\in [0, 1]$ and $b: \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ such that for all $t\ge0$ and $x,y \in \mathbb R^d$ we have $|b(t, 0)| \le \kappa_1$ and $|b(t, x) - b(t, y)| \le \kappa_1 ( |x-y| \vee |x-y|^\beta )$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^d$. I'm reading section 1.2 in the paper [Density and gradient estimates for non degenerate Brownian SDEs with unbounded measurable drift](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2020.09.004).

---

To state our main result, we need to prepare some deterministic regularized flow associated with the drift $b$. Let $\rho$ be a nonnegative smooth function with support in the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho(x) \mathrm{d} x=1$. For $\varepsilon \in(0,1]$, define
$$
\rho_{\varepsilon}(x):=\varepsilon^{-d} \rho\left(\varepsilon^{-1} x\right), \quad b_{\varepsilon}(t, x):=b(t, \cdot) * \rho_{\varepsilon}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} b(t, y) \rho_{\varepsilon}(x-y) d y,
$$
i.e. $*$ stands for the usual spatial convolution. Then for each $n=1,2, \dotsc$, it is easy to see that
\begin{align}
\left|\nabla_x^n b_{\varepsilon}(t, x)\right| & =\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(b(t, y)-b(t, x)) \nabla_x^n \rho_{\varepsilon}(x-y) \mathrm{d} y\right| \tag{1}\label{1} \\
& \leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|b(t, y)-b(t, x)|\left|\nabla_x^n \rho_{\varepsilon}\right|(x-y) \mathrm{d} y \\
& \leqslant \kappa_1 \varepsilon^\beta \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\nabla_x^n \rho_{\varepsilon}\right|(x-y) \mathrm{d} y \leqslant c \varepsilon^{\beta-n} .\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

---

**My understanding** It seems from (\ref{1}) that we need $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}b(t, x) \nabla_x^n \rho_{\varepsilon}(x-y) \mathrm{d} y=0$. A sufficient condition is that $\rho$ is symmetric, i.e., $\rho (y) = \rho(-y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb R^d$. We have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\nabla_x^n \rho_{\varepsilon}\right|(x-y) \mathrm{d} y  &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\nabla_{y}^n \rho_{\varepsilon}\right|(y) \mathrm{d} y \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\nabla_{y}^n \rho \right|(y) \mathrm{d} y.
\end{align*}

> Could you explain how to get the inequality
> $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\nabla_x^n \rho_{\varepsilon}\right|(x-y) \mathrm{d} y \leqslant c \varepsilon^{-n}
> $$
> in (\ref{2})?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\na}{\nabla}$Note that
\begin{equation}
    (\na^n\rho_\ep)(x)=\ep^{-d-n}(\na^n\rho)(\ep^{-1}x). 
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
    \int_{\R^d}|(\na^n\rho_\ep)(x-y)|\,dy
    =\ep^{-d-n}\int_{\R^d}|(\na^n\rho)(\ep^{-1}(x-y))|\,dy \\ 
    =\ep^{-n}\int_{\R^d}|(\na^n\rho)(\ep^{-1}x-v))|\,dv
    =c_{n,\rho} \ep^{-n}, 
\end{equation}
where $c_{n,\rho}:=\int_{\R^d}|(\na^n\rho)(z)|\,dz$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: It seems from your answer that the constant $c$ in (2) indeed depends on $n$. Could you have a look at my related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453458/why-is-the-map-x-mapsto-theta-t-s-varepsilonx-a-c-infty-diffe)?

Comment: Of course, I'm satisfied. I'm just confused by the writing in the paper...